# Stuck on second loop through at the reading part of the stream

Tags: c#

```cs
public static void RemoteDesktopFunction()
{
    Task.Run(async() =>
    {
        while (!ClientSession.noConnection && data != "§Close§")
        {
            byte[] frameBytes = ScreenShotToByteArray();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[900];
            using (MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await byteStream.WriteAsync(frameBytes, 0, frameBytes.Length);
                byteStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                for (int i = 0; i <= frameBytes.Length; i+= buffer.Length)
                {
                    await byteStream.ReadAsync(buffer, i, buffer.Length);
                    await ClientSession.SendData(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).Trim('\0')+ "§RemoteDesktop§");
                }
                await ClientSession.SendData("§RemoteDesktopFrameDone§§RemoteDesktop§");
            };
        }
    });
}
```

I'm trying to add a remoteDesktop function to my program by passing chunks of bytes that are read from the byte stream. frameBytes.length is about 20,000b in the debugger. And the chunk is 900b. I expected it to read through and send chunks of data from the frameBytes array to a network stream. But it got stuck on :

```cs
await byteStream.ReadAsync(buffer, i, buffer.Length);
```

On the second loopthrough...

What could cause the issue?

Comment: Consider making the whole method async rather than using Task.Run.

Comment: gunr2171
 I still got the same issue

Comment: Probably unrelated, but what is the purpose of the MemoryStream, you just write to it just to read from it again, it seems to me? Another possibly unrelated issue is just my OCD. You are incrementing with buffer.Length instead of amountOfBytesRead.

Comment: Alexandru Clonțea
 I made it like that because the earlier version didnt work either. Also the increacment is the buffer size, which also will be the the next position toread from ?

Comment: In most cases yes, but when total size is not divisible by total size,  you will have something that is <bufferSize at the end. This is by no means a candidate for a root cause, the loop will incidentally work like this (in theory)

Answer (score 1):

There is no obvious reason why this code should hand on `ReadAsync`. But an obvious problem is that you are not using the return value that tells you how many bytes are actually read. So the last 'chunk' will likely have a bunch of invalid data from the last chunk at the end.

Note that there is really no reason to use async variants to read/write 900 bytes fro/to a memory stream. Async is mostly meant to hide *IO latency*, and writing to memory is not an IO operation.

If the goal is to chunk a byte array you can just use the overload of [GetString that takes a span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=net-7.0).

```
var chunk = frameBytes.AsSpan().Slice(i, Math.Min(900, frameBytes.Length - i);
```

At least on any modern c# version, on older versions you can just use Buffer.BlockCopy, no need for a memory stream.

All this assumes your actual idea is sound. I know little about RDP, but it seems odd to convert a array of more or less random data to a string as if it was UTF8 encoded. Normally when sending binary data over a text protocol you would encode it as a base64 string, or possibly prefix it with a command that includes the length. I'm also not sure what the purpose of sending it in chunks is, what is the client supposed to do with 900bytes of screenshot? But again, I know little about RDP.

Comment: AsSpan is not supported in the version of c# im using sorry. Also how would I go on about using the return value for the stream?

Comment: Also why do I need base64 for bytes string is it because of potential data loss? Sorry Im a self taught developer. I miss some obviuos details...

Comment: @AlexanderJansson Text based formats and protocols may discard special characters, or treat them as control characters. So the typical approach is to convert binary data into a "safe" subset of ascii characters, typically base64, but base16/hex could also be used. There is also Base65536 for UTF32. But if you are trying to use an existing protocol you need to do whatever that protocol describes, just doing random things will likely just fail.

Comment: Thx for the attention and answers, but how would I go on a bout using the returning value solution you explained in the answer without using AsSpan?

Comment: @AlexanderJansson As described in the question, just use Array.CopyTo with a smaller buffer.

Comment: I would want to copy a block of it. Not the entire thing after a specific index. unlucky for me block copy doesnt exist on the latest .NET (Framework). Sorry for not being clear, im not on core version...

Comment: @AlexanderJansson Sorry, I mixed up my copy methods, try Buffer.BlockCopy instead, that lets you provide a count for amount of bytes copied.

Comment: block copy doesnt exist though in my verison.